# Web Scraping Linkedin Pagination does not work for searches

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I cannot get Linkedin to paginate, when I try the following:

seach url: https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Business%20Development&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL

Then I can go to the first side, scroll down (infinite scrolling), click on "Next", which works great but then on page 2 it does not scroll. I already realized that the url is not updated by adding "&page=2" so the variables for scrolling are not updated. I found another way to get this done - I just wonder where I went wrong, any pro around to fix this script?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from time import sleep

userid = 'myemail@mail.com'
password = 'secret'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login-email"]""").send_keys(userid)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login-password"]""").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login-submit"]""").click()

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Business%20Development&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL')

while True:

  SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

  # Get scroll height
  last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
  print('current url' + driver.current_url)

  while True:
      # Scroll down to bottom
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

      # Wait to load page
      sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

      # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
      new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
      print('new height ' + str(new_height))
      if new_height == last_height:
          break
      last_height = new_height

  driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//button[@class='artdeco-pagination__button artdeco-pagination__button--next artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--icon-right artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view' and contains(.,'Next')]""").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
driver.execute_script("$('.artdeco-pagination__button--next').click()")
```

You shouldn't need to scroll.